# Linear diphantine equation problem with right triangle sides

Tags: number-theory

I have to find the lenght of the sides of all right triangles, where the sides have integer lenghts and the area equals the perimeter.

I'm up to this point :

ba = 2a + 2c + 2b

Comment: Four questions in an hour. Perhaps you could try doing your own work at some point.

Comment: Do you know the formula that gives all the integer-sided right triangles? You won't get far without it.

Answer (score 0):

**A start:** Integer-sided right triangles have legs $2kst$ and  $k(s^2-t^2)$, and hypotenuse $k(s^2+t^2)$, where $k$, $s$, $t$ are positive integers with $s\gt t$,  $s$ and $t$ relatively prime,
 and of opposite parity.

The perimeter is $2ks(s+t)$ and the area is $k^2 st(s^2-t^2)$. Set these equal to each other.